# Referencing Excel Add-In Macro in XLSX using From Button

Tags: excel, vba, forms, button

My team has created an Excel Add-In that using the framework created by the IPSUMS project (see https://tech.popdata.org/unicorn-2-version-control/). With a little effort, this allowed us to start leveraging GitHub version control in our code project and we moved all this code into the Add-In. This Add-In is working great when referencing one of our dashboards that is another Macro Enabled Excel file because this allows us to use ActiveX buttons to refer to code in the Add-In (which we call directly in the button's _Click() Event).

One of our Excel files is our Customer Database which we turned into a Macro DISABLED file (XLSX) a couple of years ago because of the number of users accessing this SharePoint file and the need to save simultaneously. This works well when it is an xlsx, but when it is a xlsm, it causes significant conflicts and additional versions being created.

We have a few buttons within this Customer Database that point to an independent macro file, and this works ok. The problem is whenever I point the buttons (form controls) to the Add-In, it works on the computer it was created on, but since it uses a computer-based path instead of a URL to the SharePoint file, when a second user opens the workbook, the buttons do not work for them.

Is there a way to keep the Form Buttons within the file and still have them reference the Add-In (which is also resident on the SharePoint). Since I can reference an independent macro file, this seems like it should be possible, but I am drawing a blank on its implementation.

Thanks for the help in advance.